# How to add a dynamic content to Jenkins build email

Tags: email, jenkins

My automation scripts generates a Test Cycle Name where the latest test results are located. How do I add the information about the Test Cycle Name in the Jenkins build success email?

Answer (score 1):

have a  look at [Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) .

for the `Test Cycle Name`

- it could be stored in property file ,and read from [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin)
- it could call some rest-api to store/read it.